How can I use lua language json.encode without breaking the order of the list?
I have a list like below in Lua, I send this list to the js side in json format using json.encode() code. But the problem is that the order of this list is changed by json.encode every time. So my list is in an order like 1,2,3 and after json.encode it becomes 2,1,3 or 3,2,1 or 3,1,2. Each time the list is out of order.
How can I solve this problem?
Sample list :
GAMES = 
{
    ["777_Thimble"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/777thimble_logo.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777e_Thimble"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777_Thimblet"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777e_Thimbrle"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777_Thimbgle"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777e_Thimbfle"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777_Thimbled"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777e_Thimble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    ["777e_Thidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Tdhidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Thicxdmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Thidmbxle2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Tchidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_dTchidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Tdchidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
    ["777e_Tcdhidmble2"] = 
    {
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
    },
}

I have made many attempts but without any results
I am waiting for your support.

Order of keys is not guaranteed in objects. For that you should use an array. You can move the key of each item as its id, for example.
local gamesArray = {
    {
        ["id"] = "777_Thimble",
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/777thimble_logo.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    {
        ["id"] = ,"777e_Thimble"
        ["game_name"] = "777 Thimble",
        ["game_thumbnail"] = "img/game_bg.svg",
        ["1x_multiplier"] = 2.88,
        ["2x_multiplier"] = 1.44,
        ["first_bet"] = 50,
        ["second_bet"] = 100,
        ["third_bet"] = 250,
        ["four_bet"] = 1000,
        ["five_bet"] = 5000,
        ["min_attributable_bet_value"] = 5,
        ["max_attributable_bet_value"] = 10000,
    },
    -- more entries ...
}



